# why the class contructor never called?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

I'm confused with following code,

```
package test;

public class Test {        
    FooC fooC = new FooC();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("started");
        Test t = new Test();
    }        

    public class FooA {
        public int[] mData;
        public FooA() {
            System.out.println("aa");
            mData = new int[32];
        }
    }

    public class FooB {
        public FooA[] mFooA;
        public FooB() {
            System.out.println("bb");
            mFooA = new FooA[12];
        }
    }

    public class FooC {
        public FooB mFooB;
        public FooC() {
            System.out.println("cc");
            mFooB = new FooB();
        }
    }
}
```

when running, the output is:

```
started
cc
bb
```

why the FooA constructor never called? I'm a little new to java, any help means a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`mFooA = new FooA[12];` --> you are creating an Array which can hold 12 FooA instances. You have not created a FooA instance like  this : `new FooA()`

Comment: neither `new FooA()[12]` nor `new FooA[12]()` compiles, you can't do this in java?

Comment: You will have to create some objects of FooA using `new FooA()`. your *syntax* is incorrect.

Comment: @jangercarf You have to do it this way: `mFooA[0] = new FooA();`, `mFooA[1] = new FooA();`, etc.

Comment: If you want the Array filled with 12 FooA, you will need manually initialize by doing a `for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++) { mFooA[i] = new FooA(); }`

Comment: this `for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)` a little inconvenient :(, anyway I will do this for now

Answer (score 4):

`new FooA[12];` doesn't create and initialize instance of `FooA` class, but array *for* 12 instances of `FooA`. Also this array is not filled with new instances of `FooA` automatically (so it constructor is not invoked) but with `null`s. Few of the reasons this design decision was made is that

- in case of many constructors compiler can't know which one to use
- in case of constructor with arguments compiler can't know which arguments should be used

Comment: I forgot to add *your* second statement. It makes the answer clearer. :). +1

Comment: thanks guys, i didn't expect so many replies in such a short time

Comment: @jangercarf You are welcome. If you don't want to manually create array and fill it with values using loop then you can shorten your code a little using Java8 features called streams `FooA[] array = Stream.generate(FooA::new).limit(12).toArray(FooA[]::new);`

Comment: wow, this seems intimidating, I'll try that when I'm that skilled

Answer (score 1):

In Java all user defined types are instantiated when you call `new MyClass()`

In your code, when you call `mFooA = new FooA[12];` what you are really doing, is instantiating an array which can hold 12 references to `FooA` objects that live somewhere on the heap, but you haven't actually instantiated any `FooA` objects yet.

To do that you would have to do something like `mFooA[0] = new FooA();`

Answer (score 0):

`mFooA = new FooA[12];` // here you have created array which can hold reference of `FooA`

you should create `FooA();`

Comment: ye, I get it now, `new FooA[12]` won't create instances

Answer (score 0):

This isn't constructing the class.

```
mFooA = new FooA[12];
```

You need to use parentheses.

```
mFooA = new FooA();
```

If you need FooA to accept an array during construction then define it like this:

```
public class FooA {
        public int[] mData;
        public FooA(int[] arr) {
            System.out.println("aa");
            mData = arr;
        }
    }
```

And instantiate like this:

```
mFooA = new FooA(new int[12]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because

```
mFooA = new FooA[12];
```

will create only instance of array, not FooA instances. Each element of array initially will be null and you may create each instance separatly.

Answer (score 0):

`mFooA = new FooA[12];` This will create an array. You will have to set every index of that array to a new FooA.

You should change that line of code to: `mFooA = new FooA()`.